# Multiple joins in a sql query - which is best option

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I want to use a sql query with multiple joins similar to the example below.

```
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3
FROM 
table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.id1 = t2.id)
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON (t1.id1 = t3.id)
JOIN table4 t4 ON t1.id2 = t4.id 
WHERE
...
```

Would this give different results than the following query:

```
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3
FROM 
table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.id1 = t2.id)
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON (t2.id = t3.id)
JOIN table4 t4 ON t1.id2 = t4.id 
WHERE
...
```

If they are both 'correct' is the second more efficient than the first?

Thanks

Comment: what's the difference between queries?

Comment: Took me a second too.  Second left join uses t2.id=t3.id instead of t1.

Comment: Do an `EXPLAIN PLAN` and see for yourself.

Comment: They are not doing the same thing, so we cannot talk about efficiency, as it would need two identical queries. See Gordon Linoff's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The queries are different, so this isn't a performance issue.  The difference are these lines:

```
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON (t1.id1 = t3.id)
```

and

```
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON (t2.id1 = t3.id)
```

For the first, `t3.id` needs to only match `t1.id`.  For the second, it needs to match `t2.id1`, which in turn must also match `t1.id`.  In other words, the second version requires that the `id` be in both `t1` and `t2`.

This is because of the `LEFT JOIN`.  The queries would be equivalent if they used `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is more efficient because it will always return **the same or less amount of data**.

In the first query you are asking for all the records that are both in *table1* and *table4* + records from *table2* if they exists in *table1* + records from the *table3* if they exists in *table1*.

In the second query you are asking for all the records that are both in *table1* and *table4* + records from *table2* if they exists in *table1* + records from the *table3* if they exists **BOTH in  in *table1* and  in *table2***